# How to pass options to column select while extending gird with <layout>?

Tags: magento-1.9

Im trying to pass options form my source file to a custom column grid:

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_Model_Source_Order_Way
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{

    /**
     * Retrieve all options array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_options)) {
            $this->_options = [
                [
                    "label" => "Website",
                    "value" => 1
                ],
                [
                    "label" => "Phone",
                    "value" => 2
                ],
                [
                    "label" => "Email",
                    "value" => 3
                ],
            ];
        }

        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $_options = [];
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            $_options[$option["value"]] = $option["label"];
        }

        return $_options;
    }

    /**
     * Get a text for option value
     *
     * @param string|integer $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        $options = $this->getAllOptions();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if ($option["value"] == $value) {
                return $option["label"];
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

And I'm stuck in options tag. I don't know how to pass path to source file and method?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <sales_order_grid_update_handle>
        <reference name="sales_order.grid">
            <action method="addColumnAfter">
                <columnId>order_way</columnId>
                <arguments>
                    <header>Way Method</header>
                    <index>order_way</index>
                    <type>options</type>
                    <options>...</options>
                </arguments>
                <after>status</after>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </sales_order_grid_update_handle>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
        <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_index>
        <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I want add select column to grid with my options with <layout> update